# How can I remove small, paint brush marks off rough, natural wood interior beams?

Tags: wood, paint

Our post & beam house has paint marks on the posts and beams from a past owner. They were repainting the drywall and did not tape off. Since the wood is rough cut my concern is sanding will stand out as much as paint marks do. How can I remove paint and maintain integrity of rough wood?

Comment: Hi Karen, welcome to StackExchange. This is unfortunately going to be a nightmare to rectify. Anything like this is very much a "prevention is better than cure" type of thing. You're mainly looking at using chemical means to strip the paint, but rough surfaces are notorious for requiring a lot (and I mean *a lot*) of tedious picking and scraping to get paint residue from nooks and crannies, down to the level of using dental picks. Not joking! This isn't a task to take on lightly so right now might be the time to ask yourself a hard question, how much do you love the natural look of the beams?

Comment: A picture or two might be helpful here.

Comment: Have you abandoned this Question Karen? Did you get answers elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Careful application of a heat gun might help to soften the paint, making it easier to remove with a stiff brush. Heat guns can put out enough heat to scorch wood, though, and the rough surface might be especially vulnerable to damage. Test on a scrap or hidden area until you get a feel for softening the paint without damaging the wood.

Answer (score 0):

Stiff brushes of increasing stiffness. Start with nylon and move up to steel. Be very gentle because you’re trying to remove finish but not wood pulp.

If you need to go to town, get a drill mounted nylon brush wheel.

You’ll definitely going to be refinishing.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you provided more details and explanation.

Comment: I tried sanding and it was a fail. I'm going to try wire brush and gently try to remove paint. Fingers crossed.